# Trying to handle view clicks in a grid view

Tags: java, android

I am trying a create a game of tic-tac-toe where I have set the views invisible and when the user will click it I will make it visible. My app is crashing when I am clicking the image whose src is initially not set.

When I gave the image view an id and created it's onclick listener then it worked fine but I don't want to create onclick listener for every view and also give them any id and has too handle them.

This is the java code:

```
package com.example.connect3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView counter;

    void dropIn(View view){
        counter= (ImageView) view;

        counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);
        counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);

        counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(300);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any reference to a grid view in your code and you should post the layout XML.

Comment: <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/asd"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"/>